# Error in function "leveneTest" in shinyapp

Tags: r, statistics, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have a shiny app that is using levene's test in one part of the app. It works on Rstudio without any error, but I faced a problem when I transfered it on the web (using shinyapp.io). The app is runing but I can't see the result of levene's test.

Error:

```
An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.
```

I found the error from Logs :

```
Error in leveneTest: could not find function "leveneTest"
```

Why does it happened only on the web?

Comment: Is package {car} (containing `leveneTest`) both installed on the server and loaded by your app?

Comment: It's installed on my app, I haven't any errors on Rstudio. But I am not sure it's installed on the web, how can I be sure about it?

Comment: There's perhaps a dedicated feature in your shinyapps.io account, if not, you can include `verbatimTextOutput('log')` in your UI part and render the messages, error or success, using `output$log <- shiny::renderPrint(require(cars))` from your server part. 
`